# In Python, why is list(None) an error but [None] is not?

Tags: python, list

Passing `None` to Python's `list` constructor is a `TypeError`:

```
>>> l = list(None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

But using brackets to instantiate a `list` is fine; using `None` with the built-in functions is also fine:

```
>>> l = [None]
>>> l.append(None)
>>> l
[None, None]
```

My understanding was that `list()` and `[]` were equivalent ways of creating a new `list`. What am I missing?

Comment: No, `list()` and `[]` are **not** equivalent. `list([...])` and `[...]` would be equivalent. `list('a', 'b', 'c')` *doesn't work either*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think that's exact.  `list([...])` will create a copy.

Comment: @wim: Sure, and the list you passed in is discarded again. The end result is the same. The point is more that `list(...)` is not the same here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They are *not* equivalent. `list()` attempts to iterate over its argument, making each object a separate list item, whereas a list literal `[]` just takes exactly what it's given. Compare:

```
>>> list("foo")
['f', 'o', 'o']
>>> ["foo"]
['foo']
```

You can't iterate over `None`, hence the error. You will get the same with any non-iterable argument:

```
>>> list(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    list(1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

To get the equivalent of `a = [None]` using `list()`, you would have to pass it an iterable with a single object in, e.g.

```
a = list([None])
```

although this will create the list literal and then copy it, so is not terribly useful in this trivial example!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `[None]` you are creating a new list, with one element, which is `None`. To use `list` constructor you can copy such a list like this:

```
list([None])
```

`list` constructor accepts iterables (object over which it can iterate), not single elements.

Answer (score 1):

Because as the traceback said, `list` expects an iterable (list, tuple, etc...) , and None is not one. For instance, this will work :

```
list([None])
list((1, 2, 3))
```

This will fail:

```
list(None)
list(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply because `[None]` is not an empty list, as it contains `None`!

```
>>> len([None])
1
>>> len(None)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>>> len([])
0
```