# difference between [] and list() in python3

Tags: list, python-3.x

I thought that [] and list() were two equal ways to create a list. But if you want a list with dictionnary keys,

```
var = [a_dict.keys()]
```

doesn't work since `type(var)` is `[dict_keys]`, correct syntax is :

```
var = list(a_dict.keys())
```

I couldn't find an good explanation on this behaviour. Do you have one ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Python, why is list(None) an error but \[None\] is not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120448/in-python-why-is-listnone-an-error-but-none-is-not)

Comment: what i learn from this, always using new_list = list() is safier than new_list = []. afterwards one does not mix both syntax.

Comment: Once you understand the difference between the two forms, it's not a problem. However, if you feel the extra few characters saves you some confusion, go for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR:

- `list()` is the same as `[]`
- `list(obj)` is not the same as `[obj]`

`a_dict.keys()` is a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), it returns an object which can be iterated to yield the keys of `a_dict`.  So this line:

```
[a_dict.keys()]
```

is saying in python "I'm making a list with one element in it" and that one element is the dict keys iterator.  It's a *list literal* in the syntax.

Now this line:

```
list(a_dict.keys())
```

is a call to the [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) builtin function.  This function `list` attempts to iterate the argument and produce a list.  It's a *function call* in the grammar.

The equivalent list literal (actually list comprehension) would be instead:

```
[key for key in a_dict.keys()]
```

Finally, note that dictionary objects iterate by keys anyway, 
 `list(a_dict.keys())` would usually be written more simply as as `list(a_dict)` instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a_dict.keys()]
```

This one puts a single element in the list. Just as if you were to write [1]. In this case that one element is going to be a list.

```
list(a_dict.keys())
```

The constructor accepts a sequence and will add all elements of the sequence to the container.

Comment: And note that this has nothing to do with `dict_keys`, `[anything]` always constructs a single-element list and `list(iterable)` always makes a list by iterating over `iterable`.

Comment: Also note that all the other containers work similarly.